# Почему получаю Flask cors error, хотя cors настроены?

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, paypal

Почему получаю Cors error? На фронтенде у меня есть handleSubmit, который отправляет запрос на мой flask сервер:

```
    const  handleSubmit = (event) => {

        const errors = validate();
        if (errors.length === 0) {
            event.preventDefault()

            let data = {
                'price': props.price,
                'quantity': nodesNumberRef.current.value,
                'total': parseFloat(nodesNumberRef.current.value) * parseFloat(props.price),
                "moduleTipe" : props.type,
                "moduleName": props.moduleName,
            }

            let res = axios.post('http://localhost:5000/payment/', data, {withCredentials: true})
            console.log(res)
        }
    }
```

Бекенд запущен на 5000 порту и там есть следующий route:

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
...
import paypalrestsdk

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/payment', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origins=['http://localhost:3000'])
def payment():
    try:
       ...
        
    except Exception as e:
        
        return f"An error occurred while formated the payment: {e}"

    return jsonify({'paymentID' : payment.id})
```

При клике на кнопку формы получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему? Ведь cors установлены и настроены.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ошибку в виде кода, а не картинкой.

Comment: Ну, если открыть [документацию](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html) и поискать там слово credentials, то можно найти какие-то опции на эту тему